# How is an empty set a member of this power set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm reading the section on power sets in [Book of Proof](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/), and the chapter includes this statement (Example 1.4 #13) of what isn't included in the power set:

> $$P(\{1,\{1,2\}\})=\{\emptyset,\{\{1\}\},\{\{1,2\}\},\{\emptyset,\{1,2\}\}\}...\text{wrong because }\{\{1\}\}\subsetneq\{1,\{1,2\}\}$$

I understand $\{\{1\}\}\subsetneq\{1,\{1,2\}\}$, but why is the last element, $\{\emptyset,\{1,2\}\}$, in the power set if the empty set is not an element of the original set?

Comment: Why do you think $\{\emptyset,\{1,2\}\} \in P(\{1,\{1,2\}\})$?  The statement absolutely never makes this claim.  It isn't true.  So why do you think the statement is claiming such?

Comment: The empty set is a subset of every set.  The power set is the set of all subsets.  So the empty set is a member of every power set.

Comment: @DougM That's not what the OP asked.  The OP asked about $\{\emptyset, \{1,2\}\}$.  That is not an element of the power set because (as the OP correctly argued) the empty set is not a *member* of the *original* set (and hence can  not be a member of a subset).  In short, the OP is 100% correct.  But the author of the book never claimed it was.

Comment: To be thorough.  $\emptyset \in P$.  $\{\{1\}\} \not \in P$.  $\{\{1,2\}\} \in P$. $\{\emptyset,\{1,2\}\} \not \in P$. And finally $\{1,\{1,2\}\} \in P$ but $\{1,\{1,2\}\}$ wasn't listed in the set claimed to be the power set.  So that set is not the Power set for three reasons.  The book gave *one*.  The op gave *another*.  I gave a third.... and maybe I missed a 4th.... who knows....

Comment: Yes, a fourth would be $\{1\} \in P$ which wasn't listed in the set.  Basically the given set over bracketed almost consistently.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just assumed that there'd be only one incorrect element in the set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is the set $\{0,1,2\}$, then $A=\{3,4,5\}$ is wrong because $3\notin A$.

It's true that neither $4$ nor $5$ are elements of $A$ as well, but one counterexample is enough to disprove a statement.

In a nutshell, you're right, but so is the book. Both statements are valid counterexamples, but one is enough.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't: 
$$
\mathscr P(\{1,\{1,2\}\})=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{\{1,2\}\},\{1,\{1,2\}\}\}.
$$
If the author didn't comment on why $\{\emptyset,\{1,2\}\}$ is not in the set, it is likely because the author intended to comment on a particular reason why the proposed power set wasn't the correct power set. That is, he decided to be explicit about why $\{\{1\}\}$ isn't in the power set. Perhaps to be more complete, the author could have commented on why $\{\emptyset,\{1,2\}\}$ is also not in the power set, but it only takes one counterexample to do the job.

Comment: I disagree that it is necessarily a typo.

Comment: @AsafKaragila good point.

Comment: It's not a typo.  In showing {{1}} was not a subset the author didn't have to say anything about {emptyset,{1,2}} and the author *didn't* say anything about {emptyset,{1,2}}.  If they author *had* said anything it'd be that it is not in the power set either.

Comment: @fleablood noted. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a "typo" but it is an omission.  However it is an omission that the author was allowed to omit.